# Python regex(need a help)

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

не могу понять как решить следующее.

```
my_string = "Россия|0|0|2 Ростовская область|0|15789563|0 Рославль|15800328|15789569|0 Россошь|15799760|15789526|0 Ростов|15800535|15789589|0 Ростов-на-Дону|15799581|15789563|0"
result = re.findall(r'\S*[^|0-9 ]',my_string, re.IGNORECASE)
print(result)
```

Выводит следующее

```
['Россия', 'Ростовская','область','Рославль','Россошь','Ростов','Ростов на-Дону']
```

Ростовская и область должно быть вместе

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import re

items = re.findall(r'[а-яА-ЯёЁ -]+', my_string)
print(items)
# ['Россия', ' Ростовская область', ' Рославль', ' Россошь', ' Ростов', ' Ростов-на-Дону']
```

Comment: Спасибо большое друг, репутацию поставлю как только смогу!

Comment: Спасибо за доброе слово :)

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что использование кириллицы в регулярных выражениях самое лучшее решение. Лучше воспользоваться *sub*:

```python
from re import sub
my_string = "Россия|0|0|2 Ростовская область|0|15789563|0 Рославль|15800328|15789569|0 Россошь|15799760|15789526|0 Ростов|15800535|15789589|0 Ростов-на-Дону|15799581|15789563|0"
result = sub(r'(\|\d+)+', r',', my_string).strip(',')
print(result)
```

Это если возвращаемый тип должен быть строкой. Если нужен именно список:

```python
from re import findall
result = findall(r'[^|\d+]+', my_string)
```